# How to Transfer multiple files using bluetooth without repetitive confirmation?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, bluetooth, file-transfer

Many times I had to transfer images from my Smartphone to my laptop. Sometimes, until 50 images. Normally, I have to confirm 50 times to receive all the images from that smartphone. Quite wasting time and annoying. So, I want with just one confirmation, it will confirm all reception.

Is it possible? I am using Android 4.4.4.

Comment: Just use a USB cable and transfer over PTP!

Comment: I know about it. But my question is using bluetooth as more practical if such method is possible.